# How to Create a new data frame column based upon GroupyBy Object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','a','b','b','b','c'], 'Score':[4,6,8,12,34,66]})
```

gives df
[image]

I want to get my dataframe as follows:

[image]

I have tried to start with using groupie

```
df.groupby('Name')
```

Which of course gives me a groupby object. I think I need to do some sort of pivot on each group of the groupby object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Column'] = 'Score' + df.groupby('Name').cumcount().astype(str)

(df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Column', values='Score')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .rename(columns={"Score0": "Score"})
)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Score  Score1  Score2
0    a    4.0     6.0     NaN
1    b    8.0    12.0    34.0
2    c   66.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: that is perfect, and very pythonic (I think). Where does the new column named 'Column' disappear to? And why is cumcount required?

Comment: @Prolle  'Column' disappears when it becomes the column names of the new table (the parameter `columns='Column'` instructs Pandas to use its values as column names).  `cumcount()` is used to generate the serial numbers 0, 1, 2 for each group of same Name.  It is used as the new column name suffix Score1, Score2, Score3, etc.  ('Score0' replaced as 'Score' specially).

Comment: ah you are quite good at explaining. Many thanks

Comment: @Prolle  Pleased to help! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = df.groupby("Name").agg(list)
print(
    x["Score"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .add_prefix("Score")
    .fillna("")
    .rename(columns={"Score0": "Score"})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
  Name  Score Score1 Score2
0    a    4.0    6.0       
1    b    8.0   12.0   34.0
2    c   66.0
```